# Optimize output when using counter?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to optimize my output after I counted all the signs in a file. For example I want to print only signs which appear more often than once.

```
from codecs import open as co
from collections import Counter

with co('test.txt', 'r', 'utf-8', 'strict') as fp:
  text = fp.read()

for char, count in Counter(text).most_common():
  if not char.isspace():

    print(char, count)
```

My Output so far:

```
c 102
a 1 
b 1
```

I'm happy for any tips or solution, especially if it is easy to folow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple solution would be:

```
for char, count in Counter(text).most_common():
  if not char.isspace() and count > 1:
     print(char, count)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
output = filter(lambda a: a[1] > 1, Counter(text).most_common())
# output = [('c', 102)]
for char, count in output:
    if not char.isspace():
        print(char, count)
```